# Difficult page make-up with centered elastic blocks

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks: one wrapper and 2 other inside the wrapper. Inside-blocks have same size.

Wrapper is elastic and its width is being changed during window resizing. 2 blocks inside wrapper are elastic too. Each of these 2 inside blocks has min-width property.

When wrapper is wide enough inside blocks are positioned in one line one after another. But when wrapper becomes too narrow blocks are positioned in 2 lines.

The final aim you can see on the picture below:

[alt text http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/9006/nessview.png](http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/9006/nessview.png)

Important moment: as you can see on the third block, when blocks are positioned in 2 lines they are alined at center.

Question: is it possible to do this make-up using *just* html and css?

Comment: I guess it depends on the specifications. Do they include IE6?

Comment: Yes, actualy my site works well in ie6 (not so well as in other browsers but without explicit defects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works in IE 7 & FF 3 for me:

```
<div style="width: 49%; min-width: 300px; float: left; background: red;">Test</div>
<div style="width: 50%; min-width: 300px; float: left; background: blue">Test</div>
```

Problem is it won't center align when shrunk, and IE 6 hates min-width.

Still looking into center align...

**Firefox only:**

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 49%; min-width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; background: red;">Test</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; min-width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; background: blue;">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, your last variant also works in Opera, Chrome and Safari. But ie.. you know)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you want the outter box to never become so narrow, that the two inside are positioned over one another?

Put minimum-width on the outter box as well, that equals the summed up min-width, padding, margin and borders of the two inner ones.
You can pretend to have min-width in IE6 as well, in this way:

```
min-width: 200px;
width: auto!important;
width: 200px; /* The last one will be used by IE6 (as min-width), the !important one by standards compliant browsers */
```

Should also work with min-height.

Comment: Personally, I'd wrap the IE6-specific styles in a conditional comment rather than using a CSS hack.